# JOIN and get some other information from another table within the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT user_id, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM bid_latlng HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

What I need to do is get the `user_login` column from the `wp_users` table by using the `user_id` within the statement above.

```
wp_users TABLE
id | user_login
```

I'm really not so clear on how to properly `JOIN` the two statements utilizing a result within the first statement...

Comment: Honestly, I'm not even sure it's possible.

Comment: Why are you beating on the `mysql_real_escape_string` drum when using `mysqli` or PDO with proper [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) would be the right way to do this? You should never be using `sprintf` to assemble SQL queries no matter how careful you're trying to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query should get you the results you need:

```
sprintf("SELECT bid_latlng.user_id,wp_users.user_login, bid_latlng.lat, bid_latlng.lng, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 

    FROM bid_latlng JOIN wp_users ON bid_latlng.user_id = wp_users.user_id HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
        mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
        mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
        mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
        mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

Comment: NICE! That worked ... except I needed to change `bid_latlng.user_id = wp_users.user_id` to `bid_latlng.user_id = wp_users.id`